# Pass data from .vue to .js file

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I'm using this [VueJS starter template](https://github.com/kefranabg/bento-starter) and I need to store additional data to the user account directly after authentication.

helper.js

```
import UsersDB from '@/firebase/users-db'

/**
 * Create new user from firebase auth user infos
 */
export const createNewUserFromFirebaseAuthUser = async firebaseAuthUser => {
  const providerData = firebaseAuthUser.providerData[0]
  const { displayName, photoURL, email } = providerData
  const userDb = new UsersDB()
  const user = {
    displayName,
    photoURL,
    email
  }

  return userDb.create(user, firebaseAuthUser.uid)
}
```

My goal is to populate a forth field called **socialLogin** with social login data that is only available after the users first login.

```
  const user = {
    displayName,
    photoURL,
    email,
    socialLogin
  }
```

[Login.vue](https://github.com/kefranabg/bento-starter/blob/master/src/views/Login.vue)

```
 methods: {
...mapMutations('authentication', ['setUser']),
async login() {
  this.loginError = null
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
  this.setUser(undefined)
  try {
    isDekstop()
      ? await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
      : await firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
  } catch (err) {
    this.loginError = err
    this.setUser(null)
  }
}
```

How to pass data from Login.vue view to helper.js?

Comment: You could import "helper.js" into your "Login.vue" component and call a function in helper from "Login.vue", passing in the socialLogin as a parameter...OR, perhaps consider using Vuex to handle state

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are exporting a function so you need to import it and make a call inside `.vue` file.

```
import { createNewUserFromFirebaseAuthUser  } from 'path/to/helper.js'

// ...

async login() {
   // ...
   createNewUserFromFirebaseAuthUser(...);
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but I don't understand yet how to pass the data to "socialLogin"  in helper.js. `  const user = {
    displayName,
    photoURL,
    email,
    socialLogin
  }` Please explain it a bit more.

Comment: Pass it as an argument to the function if you need to.